# wasn't his usual demanding himself, even saying he was guilty

Tags: meaning

> *When Marina visited Lee in jail, she knew he was guilty. Marina could see it in his eyes and Lee **wasn't his usual demanding himself, even saying he was being treated alright.***

This sentence is related to Lee Harvey Oswald's behaviour after his arrest. I am not able to understand the bold part of the sentence. Does it stem from it that LHO confessed his guilt?

Comment: The bolded section appears to contain a typo. It should read "was not his usual demanding self".

Answer (score 1):

> Lee **wasn't** his usual demanding (him)self, **even** saying he was being treated alright.

This means his usual demanding self would *not* say he was being treated alright. It was another clue for Marina.

As used here, [***even***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/even) is sense 13a:

> (*used as an intensive or emphatic particle meaning:*)
>   13a) though it may seem improbable; moreover; indeed; fully   ⇒ *"even unto death; even a fool could understand"*

She knew he was guilty, but there is nothing said about anyone else knowing, nor do we know of any legal point or confession.